# How to search regex only outside curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, string, exec, match

I have this regex variable:

```
var regexp = new RegExp(RegExp.quote(myExpression) + '\\b', 'g');
```

which searches for expression that has a space after it. (RegExp.quate() I got from this [How to escape regular expression in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript))

**I want to search for it only outside curly brackets**.

so if I `myExpression = "cat"`

and I have this string:

```
the cat { is cat { and } cat {and { another cat } } and  cat } and another cat
    ^^^                                                                    ^^^
```

I want to get a match only for the first cat and the last cat - I don't want any match for anything inside the outer curly brackets.

I found some regex for this but non of them worked as I hoped for.

what do I need to write to get it done?

thanks,
Alon

Comment: A single regular expression is quite literally incapable of detecting whether something is outside matched, arbitrarily nestable pairs of `{ }`; so you'll need to change things a bit. If you clarify what it is that you *actually* want to do, we can try to help. Can you post the code that needs to *use* `regexp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this problem of matching nested brackets is not possible to solve using a single regex. Here is my take to resolve your problem:

```
var myExpression = "cat";
var s = 'the cat {is cat { and} cat {and { another cat}}and  cat } and another cat';
arr = s.split(/(?=(?:\b|\W))\s*/g);
document.writeln("<pre>split: " + arr + "</pre>");
//prints: the,cat,{,is,cat,{,and,},cat,{,and,{,another,cat,},},and,cat,},and,another,cat
var level=0;
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if (level == 0 && arr[i] == myExpression)
     document.writeln("<pre>Matched: " + arr[i] + "</pre>");
  if (arr[i] == "{")
     level++;
  else if (arr[i] == "}")
     level--;
}
```

Comment: great - I will implement this method. I had a sense it should work that way but you really showed me how it should be done

Answer (score 0):

One strategy would be to find/replace all {.*} with empty string... then find all the cats?

Comment: Given that the OP's regular expression will always match the exact same substring (due to the use of `RegExp.quote`), the only way that your suggestion could help is if the OP's goal is merely to *count* instances of `"cat"` (which may be the case -- I don't know -- but somehow it doesn't seem very likely to me).

Comment: assuming cat was an example... and cat was actually some pattern and he wanted the contents of "cat" then it would work.  Just looking for the simplest thing that might work.

Comment: of course you have to deal with an example like:
---the cat {is cat} cat {and cat {and cat} and cat } and another cat
--- Which gets tricky to do with regex... so using a process like anubhava suggested is probably best.  This falls in the same catagory as trying to parse xml or html with a regex.